# Status bar transparent and Status Bar Text Color iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, statusbar

So I have read several posts here on changing the status bar text color and none work. So my original problem was the status bar is now transparent in iOS7 and I want it to be white with black text. So I added this to my viewcontroller.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Ok so now the status is bar is black on black, can't read the text, but at least its not transparent. So now I did the following.

Went into the plist and added this

```
View controller-based status bar appearance  NO
```

I then added this to my app delegate

```
 self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Now I have a status bar that is white but the text is white so you can't see it? Crap!

Also the following line crashes the app if run on iOS6

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Double crap!

So I removed the following line so it won't crash.

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

So stuck with white on white.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I went to the plist leaving everything else above and added this to the plist

```
Status bar style  Gray style (default)
```

Now its how I want it.